# Python NameError 8

Tags: python, enums, nameerror

I am trying to write a class with 2 functions in Python, like this:

```
class Arithmetic(Enum):
    add = 1
    addi = 2
    sub = 3
    lui = 4
    auipc = 5

    def parse(inst, *argv):
        if inst == "add":
            return calculate_add(argv)
        elif inst == "addi":
            pass
        elif inst == "sub":
            pass
        elif inst == "lui":
            pass
        elif inst == "auipc":
            pass

    def calculate_add(*argv):
        return argv[0] + argv[1]
```

and I keep getting this error:
NameError: name 'calculate_add' is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this the exact indentation you have in your code ?

Comment: i checked the indentation already, yes, i copy pasted it

Comment: Then those functions are not members of your class.

Comment: @VladCiotlaus: what you've pasted _can't_ be your real code because it's not syntactically valid Python; you need to have at least one indented line after your `class:` line, and you don't.

Comment: @DSM i have the correct indentation, if i delete the calculate_add function and use the addition directly in the parse function, it works, but i need to add more to that function, i really don't think it is about the indentation

Comment: @VladCiotlausi: the indentation you posted was _not_ correct, because (again) it **was not valid Python**, and that makes it hard to know what your actual intent was.

Comment: @DSM I changed the post, now it is the same as in my code, stackoverflow has weird code editing

Comment: Both functions should be in the Arithmetic class

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you have defined `calculate_add` *after* the `parse` function. So, when you run `calculate_add` in your `parse` function, Python does not recognize it, since it hasn't been defined yet. 
To fix it, define `calculate_add` before you define `parse`.

Comment: You don't need to define a function physically in the file above where it's called: the name only needs to be resolvable at the time of use.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you must declare the function before trying to access it. 
(It's not cool like Java)